# how to run mysql in ubuntu through terminal

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

trying to run mysql in ubuntu
typing `mysql` in terminal
and getting error

```
ERROR 1045(28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Can anybody please sort out this problem...

Comment: Did you grant permission for the root user to access the database?

Comment: What command did you execute in terminal to run mysql?

Answer (score 55):

You have to give a valid username. For example, to run query with user `root` you have to type the following command and then enter password when prompted:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Once you are connected, prompt will be something like:

```
mysql>
```

Here you can write your query, after database selection, for example:

```
mysql> USE your_database;
mysql> SELECT * FROM your_table;
```

Comment: I dont think that will work. It seem like the issue is that the root user doesnt have access.

Comment: No, I guess he have `root` access, but without using `-p` to ask for password, he cannot enter its root password. In fact, the error message says `(using password: NO)`.

Comment: thats what it will say if you dont pass in a pasword param regardless of anything else

Comment: @JohnKane Exactly. And using `-p` he will be able to enter it.

Comment: typically you wouldnt want your root user to be able to log in to the database for security, and when you set up a dbserver you create a new user and grant permissions for that user to start/stop and access the db server. It is through this user that you would log in unless you spefically granted other users access. I would be slightly surprised if the root user was granted access to the db.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run your scripts, then

```
mysql -u root -p < yourscript.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to log in with the correct username and password. Does the user root have permission to access the database? or did you create a specific user to do this?

The other issue might be that you are not using a password when trying to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just have begun using mysql.

Simple answer: for now use

> mysql -u root -p password

Password is usually root by default. You may use other usernames if you have created other user using create user in mysql. For details use "help, help manage accounts, help create users" etc. If you dont want your password to be shown in open just press return key after "-p" and you will be prompted for password next.
Hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: Using `mysql` without user or password information automatically attmepts to use "root" and no password (in fact, the error message the OP posted reflects this), making that part of your answer superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually access mysql prompt command by directly doing :

```
sudo mysql
```

If you would like to access it the "regular" way with `sudo mysql -u <theuser>`, this answer solved it at 100% for me :

https://askubuntu.com/a/784347

Comment: Please, mention where the URL include in your post redirects to.

Comment: @Pawara as the URL clearly shows it, it takes to a post on https://askubuntu.com